# Using async/await to improve performance

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreach

I currently have a service method that runs a set of "rules" on incoming data. Some of these rules perform simple checks like validating a Id number, and some go out to databases to lookup information. It looks pretty much like this:

```
public void RunRules(ValidationRequest request)
{
    // Each rule returns bool for this example
    var rules = GetRules();

    var results = List<bool>();

    Parallel.ForEach(rules, rule =>
    {
        var result = rule();

        lock(results)
            results.Add(result);
    });

    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        RecordResultInDatabase(result);
    }

    CallNextService(someNewRequest);
}
```

I think (but am not sure) that I could improve things using `async/await`. My idea is, when one rule finishes it could then call `RecordResultInDatabase` while other rules are still running.

As a requirement though, I wouldn't want a call to `CallNextService` to happen until all rules have ran and their results recorded in the database.

Problem is I'm an absolute noob to `async/await` and I think (but am not sure) that the `Task.WaitAll` might be what I'm looking for.

I'm very uncertain of how do this, but something like this I'm guessing:

```
List<Task<bool>> ruleTasks = GetRules();
Task.WaitAll(ruleTasks);

// Somehow get the results of the rules and record them in the db???
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're locking on every parallel loop? It would appear you're turning your parallel loop into a non-parallel one by locking on every iteration for the entirety of the loop..

Comment: The expensive process is the call to `rule()` not adding to the results... only adding the result is within the lock

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.  Each `Task<bool>` you create has a `Result` property which is the return value of the Task.  You can simply have each task run itself then record the result in the database and finally return the bool.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `async`-`await` will improve performance in your case. In short, `async`-`await` is useful in two cases:

1. To improve responsiveness of GUI applications.
2. To improve scalability of server applications.

Neither of those seems to be your case, so there is no reason to use `async`-`await` in your code.

If you want to call `RecordResultInDatabase()` while requests are being processed, instead of when all of them are done, you can use PLINQ instead of `Parallel.ForEach()`. As another benefit, it will also simplify your code:

```
var results = GetRules().AsParallel().Select(rule => rule());

foreach (var result in results)
{
    RecordResultInDatabase(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not after await/async: those are designed to suspend execution of a method in a GUI application while preventing the GUI from freezing, and to improve scalability in server scenarios because it can sometimes avoid using a "thread" for the "await". Since you don't seem to be waiting for asynchronous operations and this is not a GUI then neither of this applies to you.

The client calling your service *might* employ await/async, but that's a different problem.

What you could look into is `Task` (the parallel task library). **But only if your tests truly can run in parallel and are substantial enough to be worth it**! For tiny, fast & simple tests running them in parallel will likely hurt performance, not improve.

Finally, since this runs on a server, you need to take into account concurrent activities: is the server only servicing *this* request? Unless that's true you shouldn't use threads at all, keep things single-threaded and clean. Since all CPU-threads would be tied up in servicing other concurrent requests, running multiple Tasks or a ParallelLoop will *only* hurt performance, and not just for this request but for every other request that runs at the same time. That's because there would be no "free" cores to take your threads yet you do request them. There's no extra CPU capacity to tap into. You just end up doing context-switching (and paying the penalty for that) without getting any benefit.

As always: test, test, test.

Task class on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: `await` can be useful on the server too. But it improves scalability (how many requests can run at the same time), not raw performance (how fast each request completes).